# Responsive HTML working on mobile emulator, but not on mobile

Tags: android, css, mobile, responsive-design

[This simple HTML site](http://www.rebajapp.com/bz) is intended to be responsive. From any phone emulator (i.e. mobilephoneemulator.com) the text is correctly displayed in 5 rows. Same happens when I manually adapt the width of my browser. However, when I try it from my Android 4.2 (Chrome and native browser), it is not responsive at all (text in only 2 rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this meta tag to your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

I think that should fix it